# Paypal automatic redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Since yesterday, once a user approved the pre-approval payment, Paypal is not redirecting the user anymore to the merchant page (us). Basically user is getting stuck on the confirmed payment on Paypal and his only way to come to the merchant is by clicking on "return”.

It happened all of the sudden.
We have email paypal tech team but honestly, last time we posted an issue, they never replied.

Here is the code on our side ( we have not modified it for the past 1 year)-->Ruby integration:

```
return redirect_to project_path(@project)
```

Now I am not sure whether "return_url"  is the automatic return or the button itself.

If there is anything to twick, what would that be?

Thank you for your guidance in advance.
Mel

Answer (score 0):

The *returnUrl* is for both. They should be redirected after about 5 seconds with no action. There aren't any variables you can pass to change this process. I've had the redirect not work but it was resolved by clearing cache. If that doesn't work then contacting PayPal MTS is the best option.